# Exposing an API of a library constructed with dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How should I expose an API from a project that is built using dependency injection?

1. Telling the API user to instantiate with my injection "configuration" sounds wrong.
2. Writing  some facade that instantiates it sounds like writing useless code.

Comment: See this article: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/

Comment: Thanks Steven it looks like an excellent read, though it looks like I will need a facade class which I prefer to avoid.